# Not able to redirect to other pages in Reactjs V16.x.x

Tags: reactjs

I'm a new user to react.js, trying to make a simple login page that takes the credentials of the user as input but after authentication , I'm not able to redirect into other page programatically. I'm using react.js V16.X and 
i've tried using

- Redirect
- this.history.props.push()

Help me out with this

```
    class Login extends Component{

  static contextTypes={
    router: PropTypes.object
  };
  constructor(){
    super()
    {
      this.state ={
        username: '',
        password: '',
        toDashboard: false,
      };
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.login=this.login.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
 this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}
  login(e)
  {
    //console.log(this.state.username);
    // if(this.state.username==="asdf")
    // {
    //   console.log(this.props);
    //
       this.setState({toDashboard:true})
    // }


  }
  render()
  {
    console.log(this.state.toDashboard);
    if(this.state.toDashboard===true){

    return(
      // <Router>
      // <Redirect to="/login" Component={After}/>
      // </Router>
    histroy.push("/")
    )
    console.log("in if statement");
  }
    return(
      <div>
      <div>
      <input value={this.state.username} type="text" name="username" onChange={this.handleChange}/ >
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div>
      <input value={this.state.password} type="password" name="password" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      </div>
      <div>
      <button type="submit" name="click" onClick={this.login}>button</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login
```

Comment: Are you using React Router?

Comment: yes i'm using the router

Comment: Then please show us some code, related components etc.

Comment: `this.props.history.push("/after")` this won't redirect you. This snippet will only change the url.

Comment: login(e)
  {
    console.log(this.state.username);
    if(this.state.username==="asdf")
    {
      console.log(this.props);

      this.setState({toDashboard:true})
    }

  }
  render()
  {
    console.log(this.state.toDashboard);
    if(this.state.toDashboard===true){
      <Redirect to="/login" Component={After}/>
    console.log("in if statement");
  }